# Set Time Zone To Germany in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

My site is hosted on a server in an Asian country. And I want to change the time zone for displaying the events to Germany, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
i'm used timezone: 'Europe/Berlin' in fullCalendar
But this Code not work !!!
thank you

Edit :

```
a.$calendarObj = a.$calendar.fullCalendar({
                slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
                slotDuration: "00:10:00",
                minTime: "00:00:00",
                maxTime: "23:59:00",
                defaultView: "month",
                allDaySlot: 0,
                handleWindowResize: !0,
                height: l(window).height() - 200,
                header: {
                    left: "prev,next today",
                    center: "title",
                    right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
                },
                events: "/Calender/GetEvents",
                editable: 1,
                droppable: 1,
                eventLimit: 1,
                selectable: 0,
                displayEventTime: 1,
                timezone: 'Europe/Berlin'
});
```

Comment: did you forget to share the code. Please do.

Comment: we a) don't know precisely what "not working" means (e.g. maybe you get an error, or some unexpected output), so please clarify that, and b) you need to show your code, because we cannot fix your code if we cannot see it. If you still need our help, please update your question. If you no longer need our help, please delete your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Pbd code added

Comment: @ADyson updated and code added

Comment: Thanks. Please also define "not working" more clearly, as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not fix for me.
i change timezone:

`timezone: 'Europe/Berlin'` to `timezone: 'local'`

and buy new server from Germany and it fixed.